# How to replace a token value in ACE Editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

The usage in my case is that, I'm making a content assist which replaces current token at the cursor position, by clicking on a list item,
but how to replace the active token value **"in"** with the text **"infobar"** (as shown in the image)

[image: 'in' token refers to the list]

Answer (score 0):

after researching the doc I found this solution,
but not sure if there is a better way

```
$(".menu-item").on("click", function(){
  editor.removeWordLeft();
  editor.insert("value");
});
```

it worked for me